# error regarding heroku deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku

So im in the process of deploying my code via heroku but have recently encountered 'were sorry but something went wrong' error when going to the site. Not entirely sure the cause of this Ive gone back and tried using 'heroku rake db:reset command' (that may not be verbatim) but Im a bit confused in regards to what to do to fix this.

```
    2012-08-11T23:30:00+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Awaiting client
    2012-08-11T23:30:00+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec                                 rake db:rollback`
    2012-08-11T23:30:01+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2012-08-11T23:30:06+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Process exited with status 0
    2012-08-11T23:30:06+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from up to complete
    2012-08-11T23:30:17+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Awaiting client
    2012-08-11T23:30:17+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec         rake db:migrate`
    2012-08-11T23:30:17+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2012-08-11T23:30:26+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2012-08-11T23:30:26+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from up to complete
    2012-08-11T23:32:07+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Awaiting client
    2012-08-11T23:32:07+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
    2012-08-11T23:32:07+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2012-08-11T23:32:15+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2012-08-11T23:32:15+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from up to complete
    2012-08-11T23:32:53+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Awaiting client
    2012-08-11T23:32:53+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
    2012-08-11T23:32:54+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2012-08-11T23:33:00+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2012-08-11T23:33:00+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from up to complete
    2012-08-11T23:35:36+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Awaiting client
    2012-08-11T23:35:36+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:reset`
    2012-08-11T23:35:37+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2012-08-11T23:35:52+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Process exited with status 0
    2012-08-11T23:35:52+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from up to complete
    2012-08-11T23:36:05+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
    2012-08-11T23:36:05+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Awaiting client
    2012-08-11T23:36:05+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2012-08-11T23:36:17+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Process exited with status 0
    2012-08-11T23:36:17+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from up to complete
    2012-08-11T23:37:07+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2012-08-11T23:37:07+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2012-08-11T23:37:07+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 71.201.189.216 at 2012-08-11         23:37:07 +0000
    2012-08-11T23:37:07+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by MainController#home as HTML
    2012-08-11T23:37:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered main/home.html.erb within layouts/application (1.2ms)
    2012-08-11T23:37:08+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 671ms
    2012-08-11T23:37:08+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2012-08-11T23:37:08+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (Unexpected token         name, expected punc (line: 10703, col: 9, pos: 383443)
    2012-08-11T23:37:08+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2012-08-11T23:37:08+00:00 app[web.1]: Error
    2012-08-11T23:37:08+00:00 app[web.1]:     at new JS_Parse_Error (/tmp/execjs20120811-2-2siv6i.js:3096:22)
    2012-08-11T23:37:08+00:00 app[web.1]:     at js_error (/tmp/execjs20120811-2-2siv6i.js:3104:15)
    2012-08-11T23:37:08+00:00 app[web.1]:     at token_error (/tmp/execjs20120811-2-2siv6i.js:3564:17)
    2012-08-11T23:37:08+00:00 app[web.1]:     at croak (/tmp/execjs20120811-2-2siv6i.js:3557:17)
    2012-08-11T23:37:08+00:00 app[web.1]:     at expect_token (/tmp/execjs20120811-2-2siv6i.js:3577:17)
    2012-08-11T23:37:08+00:00 app[web.1]:     at expect (/tmp/execjs20120811-2-2siv6i.js:3580:40)
    2012-08-11T23:37:08+00:00 app[web.1]:     at object_ (/tmp/execjs20120811-2-2siv6i.js:3968:56)
    2012-08-11T23:37:08+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /tmp/execjs20120811-2-2siv6i.js:3929:51
    2012-08-11T23:37:08+00:00 app[web.1]:     at maybe_unary (/tmp/execjs20120811-2-2siv6i.js:4028:27)
    2012-08-11T23:37:08+00:00 app[web.1]:     at expr_ops (/tmp/execjs20120811-2-2siv6i.js:4055:32)
    2012-08-11T23:37:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   (in /app/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)):
    2012-08-11T23:37:08+00:00 app[web.1]:     26:   
    2012-08-11T23:37:08+00:00 app[web.1]:     25:   <title>Live Well Chicago L.L.C</title>
    2012-08-11T23:37:08+00:00 app[web.1]:     27:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
    2012-08-11T23:37:08+00:00 app[web.1]:     28:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    2012-08-11T23:37:08+00:00 app[web.1]:     30: </head>
    2012-08-11T23:37:08+00:00 app[web.1]:     29:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    2012-08-11T23:37:08+00:00 app[web.1]:     31: <body><br />
    2012-08-11T23:37:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:28:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___3454440193923948893_37164960'
    2012-08-11T23:37:08+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2012-08-11T23:37:08+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2012-08-11T23:37:08+00:00 heroku[router]: GET smooth-dusk-9878.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=680ms status=500 bytes=643
    2012-08-11T23:37:08+00:00 heroku[router]: GET smooth-dusk-9878.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=0
    2012-08-11T23:37:10+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2012-08-11T23:37:10+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2012-08-11T23:37:10+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 71.201.189.216 at 2012-08-11 23:37:10 +0000
    2012-08-11T23:37:10+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by MainController#home as HTML
    2012-08-11T23:37:10+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered main/home.html.erb within layouts/application (1.4ms)
    2012-08-11T23:37:11+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 723ms
    2012-08-11T23:37:11+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2012-08-11T23:37:11+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (Unexpected token name, expected punc (line: 10703, col: 9, pos: 383443)
    2012-08-11T23:37:11+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2012-08-11T23:37:11+00:00 app[web.1]: Error
    2012-08-11T23:37:11+00:00 app[web.1]:     at new JS_Parse_Error (/tmp/execjs20120811-2-1und2hm.js:3096:22)
    2012-08-11T23:37:11+00:00 app[web.1]:     at croak (/tmp/execjs20120811-2-1und2hm.js:3557:17)
    2012-08-11T23:37:11+00:00 app[web.1]:     at js_error (/tmp/execjs20120811-2-1und2hm.js:3104:15)
    2012-08-11T23:37:11+00:00 app[web.1]:     at expect_token (/tmp/execjs20120811-2-1und2hm.js:3577:17)
    2012-08-11T23:37:11+00:00 app[web.1]:     at token_error (/tmp/execjs20120811-2-1und2hm.js:3564:17)
    2012-08-11T23:37:11+00:00 app[web.1]:     at object_ (/tmp/execjs20120811-2-1und2hm.js:3968:56)
    2012-08-11T23:37:11+00:00 app[web.1]:     at expect (/tmp/execjs20120811-2-1und2hm.js:3580:40)
    2012-08-11T23:37:11+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /tmp/execjs20120811-2-1und2hm.js:3929:51
    2012-08-11T23:37:11+00:00 app[web.1]:     at maybe_unary (/tmp/execjs20120811-2-1und2hm.js:4028:27)
    2012-08-11T23:37:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   (in /app/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)):
    2012-08-11T23:37:11+00:00 app[web.1]:     at expr_ops (/tmp/execjs20120811-2-        1und2hm.js:4055:32)
    2012-08-11T23:37:11+00:00 app[web.1]:     25:   <title>Live Well Chicago L.L.C</title>
    2012-08-11T23:37:11+00:00 app[web.1]:     26:   
    2012-08-11T23:37:11+00:00 app[web.1]:     27:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
    2012-08-11T23:37:11+00:00 app[web.1]:     28:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    2012-08-11T23:37:11+00:00 app[web.1]:     29:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    2012-08-11T23:37:11+00:00 app[web.1]:     30: </head>
    2012-08-11T23:37:11+00:00 app[web.1]:     31: <body><br />
    2012-08-11T23:37:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:28:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___3454440193923948893_37164960'
    2012-08-11T23:37:11+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2012-08-11T23:37:11+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2012-08-11T23:37:11+00:00 heroku[router]: GET smooth-dusk-9878.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=734ms status=500 bytes=643
    2012-08-11T23:37:11+00:00 heroku[router]: GET smooth-dusk-9878.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico         dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=0
    2012-08-11T23:37:25+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Awaiting client
    2012-08-11T23:37:25+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
    2012-08-11T23:37:26+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2012-08-11T23:37:32+00:00 heroku[run.1]: Process exited with status 0
    2012-08-11T23:37:32+00:00 heroku[run.1]: State changed from up to complete
```

Comment: So, what's at that line and position noted in the log: `ActionView::Template::Error (Unexpected token name, expected punc (line: 10703, col: 9, pos: 383443)`? Also, the log shows the command you ran - you can also get it from your command history.

Comment: normalocity: I've been trying to figure that out myself but I'm a bit confused due to it not directly stating which file the error is arising in. I assumed due to the template error that it originated from the application.html.erb file, however that file is not even long enough for there to be a line 10000, so its left me a tad bit confused. Also thanks for the bit about command history

Comment: it turns out that the precompile error can come from comments on js files.

Comment: Best way is to check chrome JS console for errors..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have a syntax error in your javascript file?  When you deploy to heroku, does it show that it fails to precompile your assets during the deployment?

Comment: Joel: I dont think its failing to precompile my assets although I did consider that, however, after going through with the advice from (http://excid3.com/blog/heroku-actionviewtemplateerror-css-isnt-precompiled/) this blog I dont believe that this is the origin of the issue, although I might be wrong.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the logs, but trial and error might help you.  Can you delete everything out of application.js and try again? See if javascript is effecting it?

Comment: Hey managed to get it up and running it had to do with application.js not entirely sure exactly what the issue was but with the //=require_tree . line which is automatically included at the beginning of the file. However, I still dont really comprehend how it was causing the issue seeing as it was commented out but it seems that deleting it was able to fix the issue and for the most part the site is running now. Thanks for the help though I was so focused on trying to find a solution I kinda forgot about a little trial and error.

Comment: The manifest information at the start of the file still affects things even when commented out (it's kind of how it works).  There is more info here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html