# Rails gives hard to locate error when loading js file with syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4.2, execjs

I'm getting messages like this:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Unexpected token punc «:», expected punc «,» (line: 712, col: 26, pos: 23475)
```

the stacktrace points to the manifest file (`application.js`) and doesn't provide any helpful context for locating the error. Is there a way to fix this to either provide a meaningful context or to just load the files as-is so the browser can provide the offending line number? I'm * not * using coffeescript.

somewhat redacted app.js:

```
//= require_self
//= require_tree ./services
//= require_tree ./controllers
//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require_tree ../templates
```

Comment: Are you compiling the assets locally?

Comment: this is in development, so it is using the asset pipeline fallback, i.e. dynamic compilation

Comment: Post your application.js file please.

Comment: @DickieBoy it is looking like js issue ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918667/error-regarding-heroku-deployment

Comment: @DickieBoy updated question